# How can I adjust three float left divs evenly in a wrapper that still remain next to each other when ctrl- is used to zoom?

Tags: html, css

I have three divs which are floated left to each other. They are looking good when window is full size and browser zoom is 100% i.e. default normal. But when I do Ctrl- again and again upto last zoom size then the third div drops under the first two divs. How can I sort out it? I want the three divs should remain next to each other even if page is zoom out to smallest size.

This is when page is of normal size -

[image]

This is when page is zoom out to maximum -

[image]

HTML -

```
<div id="three_float_left_divs"> <!-- three_float_left_divs starts here -->
    <div class="float_left_div intro">
        <h3>About Us</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
        <span><a href="#">more+</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="float_left_div posts">
        <h3>Latest News</h3>
        <div class="post_wrapper">
            <div class="post_thumb">
                <img src="images/news.png" height="50" width="50" border="0" alt="news" />
            </div>
            <div class="post_txt">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. <span><a href="#">more+</a></span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <div class="post_separator"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="post_wrapper">
            <div class="post_thumb">
                <img src="images/news.png" height="50" width="50" border="0" alt="news" />
            </div>
            <div class="post_txt">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. <span><a href="#">more+</a></span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <div class="post_separator"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="post_wrapper">
            <div class="post_thumb">
                <img src="images/news.png" height="50" width="50" border="0" alt="news" />
            </div>
            <div class="post_txt">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy. <span><a href="#">more+</a></span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <div class="post_separator"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="float_left_div posts">
        <h3>Upcoming Events</h3>
        <div class="post_wrapper">
            <div class="post_thumb post_event">
                <div class="post_month">June</div>
                <div class="post_date">25</div>
            </div>
            <div class="post_txt">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <div class="post_separator"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="post_wrapper">
            <div class="post_thumb post_event post_current">
                <div class="post_month">July</div>
                <div class="post_date">12</div>
            </div>
            <div class="post_txt post_txt_current">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <div class="post_separator"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="post_wrapper">
            <div class="post_thumb post_event">
                <div class="post_month">Aug</div>
                <div class="post_date">8</div>
            </div>
            <div class="post_txt">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <div class="post_separator"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div> <!-- three_float_left_divs ends here -->
```

CSS -

```
#three_float_left_divs
{
    padding:0 12px;
}

#three_float_left_divs .float_left_div
{
    border:1px solid #DDDDDD;
    width:285px;
    min-height:315px;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}

#three_float_left_divs .intro h3
{
    font-size:16px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-style:italic;
    background:#E00B07;
    padding:15px;
}

#three_float_left_divs .posts h3
{
    font-size:16px;
    color:#1A3175;
    font-style:italic;
    background:#E8E8E8;
    padding:15px;
}

#three_float_left_divs .float_left_div p
{
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:150%;
    color:#454545;
    padding:10px 15px;
}

#three_float_left_divs .intro span a
{
    color:#E00B07;
    margin-left:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#three_float_left_divs .intro span a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#three_float_left_divs .posts .post_wrapper
{
    padding:10px 15px;
}

#three_float_left_divs .posts .post_wrapper .post_thumb
{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    width:50px;
    margin-top:3px;
}

#three_float_left_divs .posts .post_wrapper .post_event
{
    border:none;
    margin-top:3px;
}

#three_float_left_divs .posts .post_wrapper .post_thumb .post_month
{
    background:#0d2972;
    color:#fff;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:13px;
}

#three_float_left_divs .posts .post_wrapper .post_thumb .post_date
{
    background:#e8e8e8;
    padding:7px 5px;
    text-align:center;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#454545;
}

#three_float_left_divs .posts .post_wrapper .post_current .post_month
{
    background:#e00b07;
}

#three_float_left_divs .posts .post_wrapper .post_txt
{
    float:left;
    width:198px;
    margin-left:10px;
}

#three_float_left_divs .posts .post_wrapper .post_txt p
{
    padding:0;
    font-size:13px;
}

#three_float_left_divs .posts .post_wrapper .post_txt p span a
{
    color:#1a3175;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#three_float_left_divs .posts .post_wrapper .post_txt p span a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#three_float_left_divs .posts .post_wrapper .post_separator
{
    border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#three_float_left_divs .posts .post_wrapper:last-child .post_separator
{
    border-bottom:none;
}

#gray_div_separator
{
    padding:8px;
    background:#D7D7D7;
}
```

So how can I stop it to happening?

Answer (score 1):

```
.float_left_div {width: 33.33333333%;padding:0 15px;}
```

Comment: Not worked really! It started new issue. Now the third div has more space to its right side than the space of first div to its left. Now they have not equal margin around them.

Comment: @user3779493 set your margin to 0 then adjust your css as needed

Comment: But if I set their margins to 0 then the boxes will be touching to each other.

Comment: @user3779493 thats were the padding comes in.  Please supply a link to the example

Answer (score 1):

Try to position fixed for each div.

```
position: fixed;
```